# All bodies have rigidbody 2d and boxcollider2d and there's no collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm learning unity, and I'm trying to recreate a game of my in Unity from XNA.

I'm following this [Tutorial Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLX2vGYjWbI0SKsNH5Rkpxvxr1dPE0Lw8F) from unity on youtube, and I've used the GameManager and BoardManager to create my map.
This is my inspector on the wall prefabs
[image: Inspector On Walls]
And this is the inspector on my Player prefab
[image: Inspector On Player]

The code for the `PlayerMovement` script

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
    public enum Directions
    {
        Back,
        Left,
        Front,
        Right,
        Idle = -1
    }

    public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour 
    {

        #region Public Members

        public float speed;

        #endregion

        #region Constants

        private const float DECAY_FACTOR = 0.85f;
        private const float SPEED_FACTOR = 20000f;

        #endregion

        #region Private Members

        private Rigidbody2D rb2D;
        private Vector2 velocity;
        private Animator animator;

        #endregion

        #region Game Loop Methods

        private void Awake()
        {
            animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
            rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
            float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            UpdateVelocity(vertical, horizontal);
            UpdateAnimation();
            UpdateMovment();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Animation Methods

        private void UpdateAnimation()
        {
            Directions direction;

            if (velocity.y > 0)
                direction = Directions.Back;
            else if (velocity.y < 0)
                direction = Directions.Front;
            else if (velocity.x > 0)
                direction = Directions.Right;
            else if (velocity.x < 0)
                direction = Directions.Left;
            else
                direction = Directions.Idle;

            SetDirection(direction);
        }

        private void SetDirection(Directions value)
        {
            animator.SetInteger("Direction", (int)value);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Movement Methods

        private void UpdateMovment()
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("HOR - {0} : VER - {1} : DIR - {2}", velocity.x, velocity.y, animator.GetInteger("Direction")));
            transform.Translate(velocity.x, velocity.y, 0f, transform);
            ApplySpeedDecay();
        }

        private void UpdateVelocity(float vertical, float horizontal)
        {
            if (vertical != 0)
                velocity.y += Mathf.Abs(speed) / SPEED_FACTOR;
            if (horizontal != 0)
                velocity.x += Mathf.Abs(speed) / SPEED_FACTOR;
        }

        private void ApplySpeedDecay()
        {
            // Apply speed decay
            velocity.x *= DECAY_FACTOR;
            velocity.y *= DECAY_FACTOR;

            // Zerofy tiny velocities
            const float EPSILON = 0.01f;

            if (Mathf.Abs(velocity.x) < EPSILON)
                velocity.x = 0;
            if (Mathf.Abs(velocity.y) < EPSILON)
                velocity.y = 0;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here's an example of my problem ingame:

[image: Ingame photo]

As you can see, the player can simply move in and out of walls as if they don't have box collider.

While writing this post, I've noticed that if I give the wall prefabs a Rigidbody2D (with `Is Kinetic` left false) there's collision but the boxes move, which is the opposite of my intent. When I check `Is Kinetic`, there's not collision again.

Comment: What version of unity (Exact)?

Comment: Okay, not that issue. Secondly, anything unusual with physics, and can you post the wall script?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention - the wall script is just empty, I can remove it altogether. It's remainder of the tutorial wall script, which I didn't end up implementing because It didn't fit my game.

Comment: Did you change the Physics2D at all, with different colliding layers?

Comment: Following the tutorial I've made a new layer (and a new sorting layer but that's not it) called BlockingLayer, and both the player and wall prefabs are layered as BlockingLayer. Aside from that, I did not interact with Physics2D.

Comment: I would at least update your Unity to the latest 5.0.x build, and then try again. From the release notes, there were some funny bugs relating to physics 2d in the early days of 5.0

Comment: Ok, i'll do that. Thanks. I'll update when the update is done and I see if anything changed

Comment: Unity seems to have killed itself. I updated to V5.3.1f1 and when I launch Unity, it shows the unity popup for an instance and the process dies. ;'( Any idea why that happens?

Comment: Fixed it: Reinstalled Unity with 32bit version, and it gave me some license problems, so I deleted C:\ProgramData\Unity\Unity_v5.x.ulf and ran again and it works. I'll edit this comment regarding the previous issue. | Ran the scene again and it's not worked yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit-Your player has 'iskinematic' checked! I believe this is your problem!

By the unity docs "*If isKinematic is enabled, Forces, collisions or joints will not affect the rigidbody anymore.*" 
-http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html

<strike>1.) Make sure the 'wall' has a Rigidbody2D and Rigidbody2D.isKinematic is checked</strike>

2.) Check your collision matrix. I noticed that 'player' has a layer 'BlockingLayer'. (You'll probably want to change that) But if in Edit->Project Settings->Physics2D the 'BlockingLayer' x 'BlockingLayer' checkbox is unchecked, then that would explain the lack of collisions.

Comment: All walls have Rigidbody2D and IsKinematic is checked, that's for sure. It's not about the layers either. I haven't touched the layer interaction settings, and it still doesn't work even if I change the layer to default for everything

Comment: Walls do not need rigidbody anyway, they just need box colliders. Why is this getting upvote?

Comment: Then what do you suggest? If they don't need rigidbody, i'll get rid of that, but it doesn't change the fact that it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Solved - Player shouldn't be kinematic. IsKinematic should be unchecked, and the gravity in Rigidbody2D should be set to 0. Thanks guys. Gonna move on to the next collision bug now :)