# Unity centring camera on transform and limiting camera movement to map

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I'm learning unity and I'm recreating a game of mine I wrote in XNA in unity.

I have the main camera script to adjust itself to the position of the player transform, but I want it to be limited to the map bounds.

That gives me 2 problems:

1) Add the script portion that limits the camera movement to the bounds of the map
2) Get the actual map bounds from the mass of prefabs that are thrown on the map.

This is [another post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370294/unity-all-bodies-have-rigidbody-2d-and-boxcollider2d-and-theres-no-collision?noredirect=1#comment56482876_34370294) regarding collision with the walls that doesn't work (if you'd like, go in the post, as I would love to have some help with the collision problem as well)

This is how the camera looks with size 4.5 when I roughly centered it on the map:

[image]

This is how the camera looks with size 4.5 when it's simply showing some part of the map and is out of it

[image]

When I lower the camera size to 3, it looks roughly like so:

[image]

There are 3 things to do based on that:

1) Limit the camera size not to be able to be bigger than the map width
2) Limit the camera movement not to be able to move outside of the map
2.1) To be able to do (2) I need to get the map bounds.

To generate the map, I use the scripts from the tutorial specified in my other post, and changed to my needs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
    internal enum BlockPosition
    {
        None = -1,
        Top = 0,
        Bottom,
        Left,
        Right,
        TopLeft,
        TopRight,
        BottomLeft,
        BottomRight
    }

    public class BoardManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private const int BORDER_COL = -1;
        public int columns = 15;
        public int rows = 15;

        // Up, Down, Left, Right, TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomRight
        public GameObject[] wallTiles;
        public GameObject[] floorTiles;

        private readonly List<Vector3> floorPositions = new List<Vector3>();

        private Transform boardHolder;
        private Transform floorHolder;
        private Transform wallsHolder;

        private void InitializeFloorPositionsList()
        {
            floorPositions.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < columns; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < rows; ++j)
                {
                    floorPositions.Add(new Vector3(i, j, 0f));
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the BlockPosition based on where on the wall grid the block is
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="row">Row of the block</param>
        /// <param name="col">Column of the block</param>
        /// <returns>BlockPosition representing the position of the wall, or BlockPosition.None if it's a center block(a floor)</returns>
        private BlockPosition GetBlockIndex(int row, int col)
        {
            ///////////
            // 1 2 3 //
            // 4 5 6 // Number represents position in map
            // 7 8 9 //
            ///////////
            if (row == BORDER_COL)
            {
                if (col == BORDER_COL)
                    return BlockPosition.BottomLeft;    // 7
                if (col == columns)
                    return BlockPosition.BottomRight;   // 9
                return BlockPosition.Bottom;            // 8
            }
            if (row == rows)
            {
                if (col == BORDER_COL)
                    return BlockPosition.TopLeft;       // 1
                if (col == columns)
                    return BlockPosition.TopRight;      // 3
                return BlockPosition.Top;               // 2
            }
            if (col == BORDER_COL)
                return BlockPosition.Left;              // 4
            if (col == columns)
                return BlockPosition.Right;             // 6
            return BlockPosition.None;                  // 5
        }

        private void SetUpWalls()
        {
            boardHolder = new GameObject("Board").transform;
            floorHolder = new GameObject("Floors").transform;
            floorHolder.parent = boardHolder;
            wallsHolder = new GameObject("Walls").transform;
            wallsHolder.parent = boardHolder;

            for (int col = BORDER_COL; col < columns + 1; col++)
            {
                for (int row = BORDER_COL; row < rows + 1; row++)
                {
                    BlockPosition pos = GetBlockIndex(row, col);
                    if (pos == BlockPosition.None) continue;

                    GameObject toInstantiate = wallTiles[(int)pos];
                    GameObject instance =
                        Instantiate(toInstantiate, new Vector3(col, row, 0f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                    instance.transform.parent = wallsHolder;
                }
            }
        }

        private Vector3 RandomPosition()
        {
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, floorPositions.Count);
            Vector3 position = floorPositions[randomIndex];
            floorPositions.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
            return position;
        }

        private void LayoutObjectsAtRandom(GameObject[] objects, int amount, Transform parent)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; ++i)
            {
                Vector3 position = RandomPosition();
                GameObject instantiatedObject = objects[Random.Range(0, objects.Length)];
                GameObject instantiated = Instantiate(instantiatedObject, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                instantiated.transform.parent = parent;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets up the floors and the extraWalls
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="extraWalls">for dev purposes, amount extra walls to be spreaaround the map</param>
        public void SetUpScene(int extraWalls)
        {
            InitializeFloorPositionsList();
            SetUpWalls();
            LayoutObjectsAtRandom(wallTiles, extraWalls, wallsHolder);
            LayoutObjectsAtRandom(floorTiles, floorPositions.Count, floorHolder);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I followed the tutorial and eventually there's a Transform that holds all the instantiated map parts - it's called "Board" and it holds two other Transforms called "Floors" and "Walls", holding the floors and the walls.
How would you manage to solve those 3 problems I stated above?

I'm just a beginner at Unity, I'm just a C#/C++ developer so naturally XNA was simpler for me because it was a lot more code-centered than unity.

Edit: this is the CameraController script:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
    public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform player;
        public Vector2 margin, smoothing;

        public bool IsFollowing { get; set; }

        public void Start()
        {
            IsFollowing = true;
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            var x = transform.position.x;
            var y = transform.position.y;

            if (IsFollowing)
            {
                if (Mathf.Abs(x - player.position.x) > margin.x)
                    x = Mathf.Lerp(x, player.position.x, smoothing.x * Time.deltaTime);

                if (Mathf.Abs(y - player.position.y) > margin.y)
                    y = Mathf.Lerp(y, player.position.y, smoothing.y * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, transform.position.z);
        }
    }
}
```